# Cannot send data with HttpClient, Angular 4 with Symfony backend

Tags: angular, symfony, typescript, cors, fosrestbundle

**Solved by using NelmioCorsBundle.**

I'm using angular 4.3.3 for frontend and **Symfony3** for backend, and I use **FosRestBundle** also.

In Angular, and I'm working with HttpClient to send or request some data.

Requesting data is working good and I can display the results but the problem is when I try to send data I get this **cors** error

On the other hand I can post json data using **postman**

This is the error:

```
1:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://127.0.0.1/rest/web/app_dev.php/api/comments/new/1. Response for preflight 
has invalid HTTP status code 405
Error occured.
{"content":"test comment","email":"test@gmail.com"}
```

and this is the code typeScript:

```
    import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private globals: Globals, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}
    postComment(post) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(post);
    this.http.put(this.globals.baseUrl + 'comments/new/' + this.id, body).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log('Error occured.');
            console.log(body)
        }
    );
}
```

In th **symfony** Project: web/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 405 is “method not allowed”, right? Your server needs to be configured to allow OPTIONS requests, and to respond to OPTIONS with a 200 or 204 success

Comment: @sideshowbarker, when I use Postman yesy I send it whith "content-type: application/json" , but I don't know how to set headers with Angular :/

Comment: So you do need to figure out how to set request headers but as I commented I think the 405 indicates the immediate problem you need to fix is that your server isn’t configured to properly respond to OPTIONS requests

Comment: I'm using Symfony3, FosRestBundle for backend, and I have configured Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*". I will add it in the post

Comment: I have solved it with "NelmioCorsBundle" :)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure your server responds to the `OPTIONS` request correctly, add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

And to ensure all the right headers get sent, what you want is this:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
```

And by the way, the reason you need to deal with that `OPTIONS` request to begin with is because your code is trying to do a `PUT` request cross-origin, and that triggers browsers to automatically make a CORs “preflight” `OPTIONS` request before trying the `PUT`—to check if the server OKs it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests has more details, but that’s the gist of it for the specific case in the question.

And note that the reasons you don’t run into this with Postman include the fact that unlike browsers, Postman does not do any CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request and anyway also the fact Postman is not bound by cross-origin requests that browsers enforce on frontend JavaScript code in webapps.

Comment: I have solved it with "NelmioCorsBundle" :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the client and server are running on different domains, you will have a CORS issue, you need to enable CORS on your server side code. Domains are considered different even if ip addresses are same but ports differ.

Comment: Yes I'm using angular for frontend and symfony for backend and I'm using FosRestBundle also. I have configured Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*". I have updated the post