# "405 method not allowed" when making AJAX request

Tags: php, symfony, cors, symfony4

I am making simple todo app, with Symfony 4 in the back-end and Vue.js for front-end.

I am getting a `405` error status for unknown reasons since a few other endpoints are working correctly.

Here is part of my `listController`:

```
/**
 * @return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View
 */
public function getListsAction()
{
    $data = $this->taskListRepository->findAll();
    return $this->view($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
}


/**
 * @Rest\RequestParam(name="title", description="Title of the list", nullable=false)
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View
 */
public function postListsAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    $title = $paramFetcher->get('title');
    if ($title) {
        $list = new TaskList();
        $preferences = new Preference();
        $preferences->setList($list);
        $list->setPreferences($preferences);
        $list->setTitle($title);
        $this->entityManager->persist($list);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        return $this->view($list, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
    return $this->view(['title' => 'This cannot be null'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

the get action is working correctly here it allows me to get all lists from db

and `nelmio_cors.yaml` file:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_credentials: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'origin', 'Accept', 'bearer', 'Allow']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

as you can see POST method is allowed.

debug:router log :
[image]

as shown the method occurs under expected method and endpoint, register and login_check, where method is not specified working correctly with using POST

Network error:

[image]

and in console I am getting CORS error.

Comment: You need to ensure the server system allows OPTIONS requests. That’s a separate issue from your CORS config. If you’re running your php/symphony4 setup under Apache, then it may be that OPTIONS requests are being blocked by Apache; if so, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490500/441757 for guidance on how to make Apache allow OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Jake, seen the answer below? Any feedback?

Comment: yivi I will feedback, later i am in job right now

Answer (score 1):

You are making an `OPTIONS` request (that's a preflight request for CORS):

> [image: request headers]

But our server is telling you clearly that it only accepts `GET` or `POST` requests:

> [image: response headers]

You need to change your webserver configuration (Apache, Nginx, whatever you are using) so it also accept `OPTIONS` requests.

[Pre-flight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) are issued automatically by the browser on certain circumstances, which explains why some of your endpoints were working, and not this one.

It looks like you are using the built-in PHP web-server, which is rather limited in features. I'm not aware of any way of changing its configuration. You can try serving accessing the site on `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost`, which sometimes makes the browser being laxer on CORS requests.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

1. Make sure that apache header module is activate by : `a2enmod headers`
2. And to allow the webserver to accept OPTIONS (since it is needed for check CORS), add it to your `.htaccess` for example like this : `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"`